# Create a circle by rotating a 3d point around pivot

Tags: python, numpy

I want to rotate a 3d point and create a circle by using each rotation step. I have only a start point (pos1, 1x3 array) in the hand, which indicates, where the circle should begin. This point should be rotated in an axis in the clockwise direction, without changing the r and create 10 different 3d points around the origin, which are equally distributed on the circle, see image below:

[image]

For this, I implement the 2D rotation matrix and rotate my point `pos1` in `x` and `y` directions with given angle, but it seems it does not create a circle at the end.

```
def rotate_point(origin, point, angle):
    angle = math.radians(angle % 360)

    rotatedX= origin[0] + (point[0] - origin[0]) * math.cos(angle) - (point[1] - origin[1]) * math.sin(angle)
    rotatedY= origin[1] + (point[0] - origin[0]) * math.sin(angle) + (point[1] - origin[1]) * math.cos(angle)
    return rotatedX, rotatedY

def main():
    origin= np.array([0, 0, 0]) 
    point_to_rotate  = np.array([1.12, 199.32, 1062.88])
    theta = 10

    rotatedPoint= rotate_point(origin, point_to_rotate , theta)
    print('rotatedPoint:', rotatedPoint)
```

**Edit:** It does actually, what it should do, if I run it in a for loop, but in counter clockwise.

```
def main():
    origin= np.array([-1.14, 172.59, 1078.31])
    point_to_rotate  = np.array([1.12, 199.32, 1062.88])
    theta = 0
    for i in range(10):
        theta = theta+36
        rotatedPoint= rotate(origin, point_to_rotate , theta)
        print('i:', i, 'degree: ', theta, 'rotate:', rotatedPoint)
```

Edit 2:
If I not increment the degree but reduce it, then it creates the points in clockwise direction:

```
theta = 360
```

then in for:

```
theta = theta-36
```

Answer (score 0):

See edits for the solution of my issue. Here is a circle created based on rotated point.

[image]

[image]